# Coding convention for .Net

Tags: .net, convention

What's for you the best convention for writing code in .net ?
I mean the name of your variable, the case, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN has the [gold standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

This is really subjective. For an "objective" answer, you could do a lot worse that following the recommendations of [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).